# Looking for an advanced correction tool

Tags: resource

If I may, this question is of rather technical nature. I'm looking for a grammar-correction tool that is advanced enough to pick up on subtle mistakes, e.g., being able to tell that the phrase "Eine Frau gutes Geschmacks" is incorrect (or rather "unorthodox") and that the "von" structure has to be used instead. At the very least, it should be able to tell whether I'm using the wrong declension or conjugation. Are there any such advanced tools?

Comment: I don't think there is a tool for this. I just pasted "Eine Frau gutes Geschmacks" into Microsoft Word, and the grammar check correctly marked it as wrong and suggested "guten Geschmacks" which is the correct genitiv form. "Frau guten Geschmacks" is equivalent to "Frau von gutem Geschmack", but "von gutem Geschmack" seems to be the preferred form according to search results. (see https://books.google.de/books?id=dYKCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq="frau+guten+geschmacks"&source=bl&ots=su4uGUgjL_&sig=ACfU3U1hcVhI6A3sh1AbqNUacolUapi6TA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM3Zjpy8__AhXmU6QEHbkzCA8Q6AF6BAgNEAM )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user Bodo has mentioned in his comment, MS Word works fine. But you need to select 'German' in your language settings.

[image]

Google Docs does a good job at the task as well. In my case it also recognized the language automatically.

[image]